# The probability of multivariate normal distribution

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

Let $x=[x_1, x_2, ..., x_{n+1}]$ is a random vector following a multivariate normal distribution;

$$x \sim N(x; \mu, \Sigma)$$

where $\mu$ is a mean vector of x, and $\Sigma$ is a covariance matrix. Only $x_1$ is correlated with the other variables, and the others are independent of each other. Thus, $\Sigma$ is expressed as:

$$\Sigma = \begin{bmatrix}d_1 & c_1 & c_2 & \cdots & c_n \\c_1 & d_2 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\c_2 & 0 &  \ddots& & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots &  & &\vdots \\c_n & 0 & \cdots & & d_{n+1}\end{bmatrix}$$

In this situation, I want to compute a probability that x is in a hyper-rectangle;

$$\int_{\Omega} f(x) dx$$

where $\Omega=\{{ x \mid a_i \leq x_i \leq b_i }\}$

How can I compute that probability?
Or, how can we compute an upper or lower bound for that probability?

Comment: You can express $X_1$ as a linear function of $X_2,X_3,...,X_n$ and then make the (n-1)-dimension integral in $x_2,...,x_n$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think that given $X_2, X_3, ..., X_n$, $X_1$ still has randomness. Nevertheless, can we compute that probability which I asked by n-1 dimensional integration?

Comment: Not sure we can have analytical solution. But with this transformation, the integral becomes simpler to be applied any numerical solution

Comment: @NN2 I agree with your comments. It seems simpler for numerical solutions. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Let me change a bit your notations: we assume that the covariance of $(X,Y_1,\ldots,Y_n)$  is, by blocks $$\left[\begin{array}{cc}a&c^T\\c&D\end{array}\right]$$ where $c^T=(c_1,\ldots,c_n)$ and $D=\mathrm{diag}(d_1,\ldots,d_n).$ For simplicity I assume that $E(X)=E(Y_i)=0.$ The theory says that $X$ conditioned by $Y$ is Gaussian with mean $$c^TD^{-1}Y=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{c_i}{d_i}Y_i=m(Y)$$ with variance independent of $Y$ and equal to $\sigma^2=a-\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{c^2_i}{d_i}.$ Note that $m(Y)$ is Gaussian. As a consequence $$\Pr(x<X<x'|Y)=\Phi(\frac{x'-m(Y)}{\sigma})-\Phi(\frac{x'-m(Y)}{\sigma})=f(Y).$$ Now if $B=\prod_{i=1}^n[y_i,y'_i]$ and if $g(y)=Ce^{-(\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{y_i^2}{2d_i})}$ is the density of Y, then
$$\Pr(x<X<x', Y\in B)=\int_Bf(y)g(y)dy.$$

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have a question regarding your answer. It appears that the right-hand side of the final equation depends solely on y and not on both x and y. However, the probability is defined by both x and y. How can I reconcile your answer with the inclusion of x in the probability definition?

Comment: Of course, $f$ depends also of $x$. Sorry for a poor notation.